# How to fill_in field in one of two forms in a HTML file using capybara?

Tags: html, forms, testing, capybara

I have two forms (a sign-up and sign-in) in one html file which I am testing using Capybara's `fill_in` syntax. However both have a username field and both have a password field and I'm getting `Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching field :username` . How can I, in my spec helper methods ensure I'm filling in the field of the correct form. I would imagine I need to `id=` each form but I can't find anywhere that has a capybara syntax for that.

My html

```
<form id="signUpForm"action='/user' method="post">
  <!-- more fields -->
  <input class="entryField" type="text" name="username" required>
  <input class="entryField" type="password" name="password" required>
  <!-- more fields -->
  <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
</form>

<form id="signInForm" action="/session" method="post">
  <input class="entryField" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input class="entryField" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

And my helper method

```
def sign_in user
  visit '/'
  fill_in :username, with: user.username
  fill_in :password, with: user.password
  click_button 'Sign in'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scope the 'fill_in' instructions to a particular form. You can do this with Capybara's #within syntax, as specified here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Awithin

So your #sign_in helper might be:

```
def sign_in user
  visit '/'
  within('form#signInForm') do 
    fill_in :username, with: user.username
    fill_in :password, with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
  end
end
```